# Jquery get value of selector when using the on event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I'm using the `on` event listener to listen for dynamically added `select` elements. When an event happens is there a way to get the specific `select` element? `this` references `ul.form`.

```
$('ul.form').on('change', $("select[id$='end']"), function () {
        var selector = // unsure what goes here.
        self.modify(this);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('ul.form').on('change', $("select[id$='end']"), function (e) {
        var selector = e.target;
        self.modify(this);
});
```